How can I fix the wobbly reflections?
The reflections on my car model look wobbly like this:

As an attempt to fix this, I selected all the faces and hit Mesh > Normals > Average > Face Area. After that, the wobbly was mostly gone, but it left some artifacts in a face.

I was able to "resolve" this by flipping the faces, but they now face the wrong orientation.


I will be exporting this model to Unity, so this is clearly not the solution.
Is there any way I can flip these faces back to their correct orientation without changing the behavior of these reflections, or a whole other way of fixing the wobbly reflections?

I would verify that this issue actually transfers to Unity before freaking out about it too hard. It could be some artefact of the preview view mode in Blender. Test it in Unity with a shiny material and see if it still has the issue.

Just flip again, now to the right side. You flipped the indivuduals, now flip the whole .

I already had this issue in Unity, for over a year to be exact. The issue most likely has to do with the model itself, I just haven't figured out the solution yet. ---
@DanielMöller what do you mean by "flipping the whole"? If you mean selecting all  the faces that makes up the rear window and hitting Alt+N > Flip, that's exactly what I did. Reflections are always only correct when facing the wrong direction. If I flip them, they become distorted again (just like in the second picture). If I flip them again, they're correct but on wrong side.

Can you share your Blender project file? Instructions for sharing.

Here 

That's strange behavior indeed.... I noticed that the "merge" in the mirror is causing this, as if the geometry was flattened, which doesn't seem to make sense.
